# Why Symfony2 form show the default error value notwithstanding the validation?

Tags: forms, symfony, annotations, doctrine-orm, validation

I'm continuing my study of Symfony2 and new "problems" are found!

Let me describe the problem.
I have a class that construct a form on a Doctrine Entity. It is identical to the registration form example described at [this page of the official docs](http://symfony.com/doc/current/bundles/DoctrineMongoDBBundle/form.html). The only difference is that I use Doctrine instead of MongoDB.

Now, I added the following field into the User class

```
 /**
 * @Assert\Type(type="integer", message="Not an integer.")     
 * @ORM\Column(type="smallint", name="num")
 * 
 * @var Smallint $num
 * 
 */
protected $num;
```

Then, I updated function *buildForm* in class *UserType* by adding the following lines:

```
public function buildForm(FormBuilder $builder, array $options)
{
    ...
    $builder->add('num', 'integer', array(
        'label' => 'Insert a number',
        ));
}
```

Here is the problem. Notwithstanding that I provide a custom message through Annotation, a wrong input for the field *num* (i.e. a string value) returns the following error code: "**This value is not valid**" instead of "**Not an integer**".

Any idea about this missed interpretation of the customized error message?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try adding

```
'invalid_message' => "Not an integer'
```

In `buildForm` method.

Comment: Yes I know! But it is not the same. It is only a trick, not the answer to the question. In fact, by following this solution you will show the same error message for each invalid entry. However, through Annotation you can define different error types. Thanks anyway.

Comment: Then you have to set the field as text in `buildForm` method. `This value is not valid` is comes because of throwing exception from [IntegerToLocalizedStringTransformer](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/blob/master/src/Symfony/Component/Form/Extension/Core/DataTransformer/IntegerToLocalizedStringTransformer.php) `clientTransformer` which is invoked before any validation happens.